# Integrate or Switch between two angular application while storing data

Tags: javascript, angular

Currently I am working on multiple angular application and I want to integrate these apps.

So for example I have 2 angular applications: Product Application and Payment Application. I want to select product in Product application and then direct to payment application where i do the payment operation and after that i again come back to "Product application review page" where I show selected product and the payment information. How can I achieve this.

I have thought of following approach:

1. Angular Element of app 2 which can be embedded in app 1 but then every time i make change to app 2 i have again build and create app 2 and embed into app 1
2. Use IFrame and open app 2 inside app 1 as a pop up by passing url and parameteres in url
3. Use callback url in link when opening the app 2 from app 1 so that when app 2 operation is completed it will be back to app 1

Is there any better approach, which will be easy to use and provides maximum flexibility. Any example would be great.

Comment: Did you consider using browser storage?

Comment: Why not make one single app?

Comment: I would suggest the same as @MikeOne and build one app with two lazy loaded modules.

Comment: One of the app will be used by many other angular apps so we are making as stand-alone app .So for example Payment application is an application which will be used by other angular application in different context. so based on the context or based on the calling apps , payment app will behave differently

Comment: @GCSDC What is browser storage and how does it help in doing integration of angular applications ?

Comment: @vikastiwari I'm referring to local storage, but you will only be able to share data if both apps are inside the same domain. Still, based on your comment above, it seems a better approach to use Angular Elements as you mentioned on option 1 of your question.